# not analyzed string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a template in elasticsearch that changes all strngs to not analyzed. The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) shows that I can do that using

```
"properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z YYYY"
        }
      }
```

But the problem here is that I need to do this for every field like it is done here for `host_name`. I tried using `_all` and `__all` but it did not seem to work. How can I change all the strings to not analyzed using a custom template?

Comment: For an already existent index? If so, not possible.

Comment: I am currently setting up and testing the server, so the data indexed is hardly 5 documents.... It wouldn't be much of a problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an already existent index, you cannot change the mapping of the already existent fields and, even if you could, you need to reindex all documents so that they can obey the new mapping rules.

Otherwise, if you just create the index:

```
PUT /_template/not_analyzed_strings
{
  "template": "xxx-*",
  "order": 0,
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_fields": {
            "mapping": {
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```